# How to create simple RESTful service in IntellijIDEA 2016? (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, intellij-idea, jax-rs

My google-fu has failed me.

I have lost 2.5 hours trying to figure this out. I just want to make this simple RESTful service with get and post requests that generate hello world on get (i.e. localhost:9000/hello ) and on post prints to service console what was sent in bla variable.

I have found some simple examples

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("greeting")
public class Greeter {
    @GET
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi!!";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work intellij doesnt recognize Path and GET annotations. It asks me if I want to implement them. I've tried on both NewProj->JavaEE->Restful Web Service and NewProj->Java->WebApp->WebServices.

Some sample generated code from one of them made this @webmethod annotation for which I wasn't able to find any info on the net. And the JetBrains [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3nnjmK1GwE) from 2013 looks like an overkill/a-bit-outdated?. This is really simple app, I don't need/know how to use/ Maven.

Comment: If you'd like a simple Web server in Java, you might want to look at this.  http://sparkjava.com

Comment: I don't know why you have to do this in java. I would try go: https://play.golang.org/p/PQgrsjmih8

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the jar-file containing the classes you have imported (from e.g. http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-spec/index.html).

Open Project Structure, Go to Libraries, press the plus button, and add the jar-file to your project.